# Conditional Formatting: no color when cell is empty

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I am using this custom formula for my sheet: `=if(B2<((B$7/4)*$A2), 1, 0)`.

However, this also highlights the rest of the cells that are empty.

How do I exclude empty cells from this formula?

Answer (score 3):

Use `=and(len(B2), ... )` where ... is your current condition. The length value of 0 corresponds to False; any positive value is True.

A more explicit, but longer version is using `not(isblank(B2))` instead of `len(B2)`

By the way, your construction `= if( condition, 1, 0)` is not necessary; simple `= condition` works. E.g., `=B2<((B$7/4)*$A2)` is a valid formula returning True or False according to the condition.

So, a complete formula would be `=and(len(B2), B2<((B$7/4)*$A2))`.