# Custom formula conditional formatting highlights empty cells in red - how to fix this?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I use the ff. custom formula for conditional formatting in Google sheets:

```
=sum(arrayformula(n(regexmatch($J2:$W, "Unsure|Yes")))) = 0
```

However, it also colors empty cells.

I tried to incorporate the formula as suggested [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/79941/conditional-formatting-no-color-when-cell-is-empty)
but couldn't get it to work either.

If you need to see the sheet I'm using, here's a [copy](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fGZQYFgNnVWQkh2SUC6dEUFIJdJ5a35_968QUibxOZM/edit#gid=827423647).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to avoid coloring empty cells is to just check if the cell is empty using isblank().  Replace the formula with

```
=and(not(isblank(J2)),sum(arrayformula(n(regexmatch($J:$W, "Unsure|Yes")))) = 0)
```

I've done this for your sheet copy.